# Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to join two tables in codeigniter. I want to display data according to login user.I do it getting session id of user.it display error message which I mention on heading.when i comment " `$this->db->where("id",$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);"` this part it will work fine.

**model**

```
function get_user(){

    $this->db->select("user.firstname,user.lastname,user.address, user.email, user.contact_no, project.location"); 
    $this->db->where("id",$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']); //check login user
    $this->db->from('user');
     $this->db->join('project', 'project.client_id = user.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

**controller**

```
public function index(){  

 $data['post'] = $this->profile_model->get_user(); // calling Post model method getPosts() 
        $this->load->view('user_include/header');
        $this->load->view('user_site/profile',$data);
    }
```

**view**

```
<?php if($post) { ?> 
<?php foreach($post as $post){?> 

    <div><?php echo $post->firstname ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;'; echo $post->lastname;?></div> <br>
    <div><?php echo $post->address ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;'?></div><br>
    <div><?php echo $post->contact_no ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;'?></div> <br>
    <div><?php echo $post->email ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;'?></div> <br>
    <div><?php echo $post->location ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;'?></div> <br>

<?php } 
} else {

    ?> 
 </div>
<div clospan="4" align="center">No records found to display</div>
```

Comment: try with `$this->db->where("user.id",$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);`

Comment: Perhaps alias the where ID...  `where("user.id",$this->se`  it appears project and user may both have table column `ID`

Comment: thanks saty. it  works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column is ambiguous for database. Try changing the `where` clause like this:

```
    $this->db->where("user.id",$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
```

or

```
$this->db->where("project.id",$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
```

if that's the case. Since both tables may have an `id` column, you must be very clear which one you refer to.